# Otimização de compilação mal feita

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilação, assembly, otimização

Eu configurei o Visual Studio para compilar VC++ com `/Ox` e compilei este código (com mais outros que foram omitidos para simplificar).

```
union { unsigned long long u64 ; unsigned short u16[4] ; } x ;
union { unsigned u32 ; unsigned short u16[2] ; } i ;
i.u16[0] -= x.u16[3] ;
```

Segundo o disassembly, o `i` inteiramente estava em `ecx` e o `x` estava na memória. Eu esperava que o compilador gerasse o assembly assim.

```
sub cx , word ptr [x+6]
```

Mas o que ele gerou foi isso, ou seja, mais duas instruções precedidas que se mostram desnecessárias.

```
mov rax , qword ptr [x]  
shr rax , 30h  
sub cx , ax
```

Ou seja, carregou num registrador... e ainda carregou mais do que precisava, tendo depois que deslocar os dados. Era como se estivesse fazendo `i.u16[0]-=(unsigned short)(x.u64>>48)`! Além disso, os dados em `rax` não são mais usados (são sobrescritos), inutilizando tanto o `shr` quanto o `mov`.

Por que ele não otimizou mais? Tem mais alguma configuração necessária para melhorar esse código que até um bebê vê onde dá para reduzir operações?

Comment: Estou votando para fechar, já que não especificou a versão do compilador, e a pergunta é contraditória com a situação atual: https://godbolt.org/g/K388UN

Comment: Por mim pode fechar, ninguém vai responder... né? Mas duas coisas são certas: (1) quando precisa da versão do compilador, se avisa para colocá-la ao invés de usar como uma das duas desculpas para fechar o tópico alheio e (2) a pergunta não é contraditória com a situação porque é uma realidade usando o VS nas configurações que usei, não importa se com outro programa e outros parâmetros você viu algo diferente, isso não torna minha pergunta contraditória. Enfim, pode fechar o tópico. Mas não dá para você ficar me perseguindo por motivos de discordância em outro tópico, né? Francamente, cara...